# Run android studio app in debug mode without ads?

Tags: java, android, debugging, ads

Is there an easy way to deactivate ads in debug mode?
I'm getting annoyed from my own test ads while building my app :D
I am using IronSource mediation.

Answer (score 3):

Just add an `if` statement to check if you're in the debug mode or release mode :

```
  if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
       showAds();
    }
```